# CSS Transition on float relocation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, css-transitions

I'm working with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh2Ht/

As you can see, I have a group of float divs with the same width but with different heights. However, the container have a percentual width and as a consecuence, when changes its size the floating divs changes its position.

I would like that this change of position was animated, using css transitions. I could do that with absolute positioning, a little bit of javascript to calc the positioning and binding the transition effect to top and left propierties, but as I want to emulate exactly the behavior of float divs it would be excellent do it without absolute positioning.

Do you think that it is possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am really not sure it's possible to relocate blocks as you described with pure CSS. Mainly that's because some of the blocks would have to be moved into different position in DOM which is not possible with CSS.

Have you tried using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin? Check their website, maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Interesting. I also found this http://masonry.desandro.com/ I don't know which is the best but this last is licensed under MIT, while isotope needs a 25$ fee for commercial use (my case). Just something to take into account. The bad thing in all this is that I'm a little disapointed with the need of use javascript and absolute positioning, at least in the case where all divs have the same width. In other cases it's understandable.

Comment: FYI: Isotope uses Masonry, so its the same. But Isotope has additional features such as sorting, filtering etc.

Comment: Isotope and Masonry are from the same awesome guy, David Desandro, aka Metafizzy. He also has other scripts called Packery and Dragabilly which also rely on Masonry. The development on these scripts has involved and attracted high profile web developers, such as Paul Irish etc. and are well known across the web development community.