# Animate Window resize content rearrange

Tags: jquery, html, css

I see many themes where when window is resized it rearranges content with slight animation 
for example http://wpexplorer.me/demo.php?theme=pronto . If you make window smaller or larger it moves rows and columns accordingly . I have proper css that does the same thing but I couldnt find anywhere on js or css how to animate on rearranging .

Any help highly appreciated .

Comment: It uses `masonry.js`. Go google for it and check about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) it does just that

Answer (score 0):

There's always the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin, too. (A little [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580281/css-transition-on-float-relocation) never hurt anyone!)

Comment: Agree. user1649941: It is most surprising what a good ol' search on SO or Bing can yield. But why searching, when one can just hack one's questions into any clickable form field that comes along...

Answer (score 0):

there is also http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin for this, but as said Ibu, [the masonry jquery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/animating-css-transitions.html) do this great