# re-order boxes on resize with animation

Tags: html, css

I created an html / css code that lists the number of divs to fit the width of the screen.
I would like the divs to move smoothly when the width of the screen changes and the divs are aligned.

I do not know the exact keyword when I try to do a search.

I want to create an animation similar to the site below.
https://www.kia.ca/all-vehicles

it's code.

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.item{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 285px;
  height: 215px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are very complex scripts which do that, you should not attempt to do it by yourself, it would take you weeks. Are you using *React*?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/12287693/104380

Comment: [Shuffle](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) script can do it for you

Comment: Thank you for letting us know that this is a difficult technology.

Comment: I'll use Shuffle